# Wrapping an image with a div in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So just starting to sit down and play with AngularJs.

I would like to wrap an image with a `<div>` and have reached a (very early) point where I have little idea what I am actually doing.

My HTML is as so - notice the attribute set-background

```
<div id="home">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Site/home-background.jpg" set-background />
</div>
```

I am hoping to pick this (set-background) up in angular, then apply a class to the element and also wrap the element (an IMG in this case) with a div.

It's the wrapping-with-a-div bit that has me stumped..

This is the Angular I have so far.. (not a lot..)

I have `scope: {}` in my directive to ensure that anything i set to this element will not be affected by others of the same directive - I intend to do a lot more with this directive..

With this, I can add a class easy enough.

```
var dwApp = angular.module('dwApp', ['ngRoute']); // ngRoute will be used shortly..

dwApp.directive("setBackground", function () {
    return {
       restrict: "A",
       scope: {}, 
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         element.addClass("backgroundCover");
       }        
    }
 });
```

One of the things I have tried, to get the div AROUND the image was:

```
dwApp.directive("setBackground", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {},
        transclude:true,
        template: "<div style='border:solid 1px green;' ng-transclude></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass("backgroundCover");
        }        
    }
});
```

This resulted in the HTML - not right...

```
<img src="/Content/Images/Site/home-background.jpg" set-background="" class="ng-isolate-scope backgroundCover">
     <div style="border:solid 1px green;" ng-transclude=""></div>
</img>
```

I'm trying to get:

```
<div style="border:solid 1px green;">
     <img src="/Content/Images/Site/home-background.jpg" set-background="" class="ng-isolate-scope backgroundCover">
</div>
```

I clearly have a huge lack of understanding how this works... :)

Any help would be great - thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use `element.wrap('<div></div>');` in your directive. Using that approach, you don't need `transclude`. Also, there's no reason to give your directive an isolated scope in this case. Something could only interfere if you were going to use `scope` in the directive. I only use the `scope` property if my directive is going to use something from it.

Comment: Good god...as simple as that.. :D - many thanks. I've browsed through the docs, though found them a little overwhelming.. I'm using an isolated scope because the background will eventually be having it's `css` `top` style changed based on scrolling of the window, so don't want all of my `setBackground` to change at the same time - not sure if isolated scope is right in this case.. i'll dump the transclude too; misunderstood its use. Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren you were close with `transclude` - but it deals with the contents of the element, not the element itself.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. I watched an egghead video shortly after writing this question and noticed the directive related to an element and not an attribute.

Comment: I just posted another, slightly-related, question.. If you find yourself with any time to have a look, perhaps you would be kind enough to help? If not, no worries. Question is here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584471/angular-removing-from-strings-within-directive