# Angular removing / from strings within Directive - seems to butcher html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having an issue (just learning Angular) with a string having any `/` removed and replaced with `=""`.

I have a directive that takes it's element and then wraps it with a `div` and provides some styling to the `div` - namely a `background-url` - it is the URL that is being replaced with something else.

It may be a little odd - what I am actually trying to do here - and that's ok; i'm just trying to learn a little more about Angular and simple manipulation of elements seems a good place to tinker..

Here is what I have:

**HTML** - notice the `set-background` attribute on the image.

```
<div id="home">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Site/home-background.jpg" set-background />
</div>
```

**Angular directive**

```
dwApp.directive('setBackground', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            element.addClass('backgroundCover');
            var bgImg = 'style="background-image:url("' + attrs.src + '");'           
            element.wrap('<div class="backgroundCoverContainer" ' + bgImg + '></div>');
            element.remove();

        }        
    }
});
```

**Resulting HTML - notice the background-url**

```
<div id="home">
        <div class="backgroundCoverContainer" style="background-image:url(" content="" images="" site="" home-background.jpg");=""></div>
</div>
```

If I `console.log(bgImg)` I get:

```
style="background-image:url("/Content/Images/Site/home-background.jpg");
```

Clearly, the `background-image` isn't actually being rendered like that though...

any ideas?

Comment: just remove double quotes within `()`

Comment: That doesn't work - tried that. By doing that I get `Error: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.` - in reference to whatever is being injected into the wrap. It's like either Angular or JQuery is trying to parse my string into key/value pairs based on the `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i'm an ass....

Charlietfl's comment put me in the right direction - thanks.

I was simply missing the closing `"` to the style..

My JS WAS

```
var bgImg = 'style="background-image:url("' + attrs.src + '");'
```

When it should have been - notice the last `"`

```
var bgImg = 'style="background-image:url(' + attrs.src + ');"'
```

OR

```
var bgImg = 'style="background-image:url(\'' + attrs.src + '\');"'
```

Giving me the directive more like this - also removed the element.addClass - seeing as I was removing it anyway.... :D

```
dwApp.directive('setBackground', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var bgImg = 'style="background-image:url(\'' + attrs.src + '\');"'
        element.wrap('<div class="backgroundCover" ' + bgImg + '></div>');
        element.remove();
    }        
}
});
```

Comment: I see you got it figured out. Aren't quotes fun!? I had a situation recently where I need to write a string into the DOM that itself contained double quotes AND single quotes and in order to write it, I had to make the string using single quotes and double quotes while concatenating js variables. It's like quote Inception. =D